# ScrollViewer not working on user control wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, scrollviewer

I have a User Control 1 and a Page 1, what I'm trying to do is adding a scrollViewer to the User Control 1,  but it does not working.

I would like to know what's wrong in this case?

**Page 1 :**

```
<Border BorderThickness="0" x:Name="border1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="325"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Width="auto" Grid.Column="0">
            <local1:UserControl1  Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.Column="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ></local1:UserControl1>
            </ScrollViewer>
        
    </Grid>
    </Border>
```

**User Control 1:**

```
 <Grid Background="White">

        <Border  x:Name="border1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  >
            <TabControl 
            Background="{StaticResource WhiteBruch}"
         x:Name="TabControl1"
         Height="auto"
         BorderThickness="0" >
                <TabItem x:Name="Tab1" 
                     Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleText}"
                        Text="{StaticResource Text1}" 
                        Name="TabItem1"
                        />

                    </TabItem.Header>

                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>

        </Border>    
</Grid>
```

Comment: what do you mean scroll doesn't work? I can see scroll in your sample, but if window size enough for your control scroll is disabled.

Comment: Can you give more detail about how "it doesn't work"? Can you include a picture showing what's happening for you?

Comment: Thank you for your comments , I fixed the problem by adding Maxwidth to the ScrollViewer